# Error: ESPIPE, write

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Im using the following code to write to a file

```
fs.writeFile('/dev/ttymxc1',"LED 1 ON",function(err){
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

and I get the error

```
{ [Error: ESPIPE, write] errno: -29, code: 'ESPIPE' }
```

I already googled it but I found nothing..

EDIT:

I think the reason this does not work it that I have to use

```
fs.createWriteStream();
```

instead of

```
fs.fileWrite();
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem then?

Comment: Don't know if you can accept your own answer, but it will help yourself and others ;-)

Comment: I can accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was using

```
fs.createWriteStream()
```

instead of

```
fs.fileWrite();
```